# regex for /command followed by number

Tags: php, regex

Using the following regex doesn't work to validate /command number.
Here's what format of numbers I need to "validate"

- /command 1
- /command 0.5
- /command 0.12345678

As you may see the value needs to be positive and the decimals are maximal 8.

I've done some research and found:

```
\/command\s?[\S]
```

But this work only for /command 1.

Answer (score 3):

`\/command\s?[\S]` here `[\S]` will match only one non-space character so you can use and nothing else.

```
/command 1          //  1 : match one non-space 
/command 0.5        //  0.5 :more than one non-space character so won't match
/command 0.123456789  // won't match
```

[`\/command\s?\S(\.\S{1,8})?`](https://regex101.com/r/UEIjLN/2)

- `(\.\S+)?` : `?` match zero or one

  - `(\.\S{1,8})` match `.` and 1 - 8 non-space character

---

more specifically for digits use

To define max `8` digit limit , use `\d{1,8}`

[`^\/command\s?\d(\.\d{1,8})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/UEIjLN/7)

Note : if you want to match more digits before `.` e.g `/command 123.5` then use

`^\/command\s?\d+(\.\d{1,8})?$`

as suggested by @jen and @serge

Comment: I would disagree, OP wants a *number* while your regex would allow other characters as well (see https://regex101.com/r/UEIjLN/4). Instead, change it to [**`/command ?\d+(\.\d+)?`**](https://regex101.com/r/UEIjLN/5)

Comment: i know , `\s` would and my second suggestion is particularly based on the example demo posted by OP where i intentionally decided to keep only one digit though let me add it with a note , thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you want to validate an entire string the first thing to remember is to enclose your pattern between the start and end of the string anchors: `\A...\z`

About the number with 8 decimals max there's nothing particular to say except that if you don't want a trailing dot you need to use an optional group and the correct quantifier: `\d+(?:\.\d{1,8})?`

Note also that you are free to change the pattern delimiter with an other character. This way you don't have to escape the slash that isn't a special regex character.

Result:

```
$pattern = '~\A/command \d+(?:\.\d{1,8})?\z~';
```

*(feel free to make the space optional if needed)*

Answer (score 0):

This is because you missed '+' in [\S]+
But the above will not distinguish between numbers and other symbols.

To pick on 'numbers', you can use something like the following in 'perl'-like regex:

```
/\/command\s*[0-9.]+/
```

Comment: Yes, to be precise, you need something like in your example, Just a bit modified: *\d+(\.\d+)?*